# Excel-VBA, For Loop Syntax, placement of "for" and "next x"

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub test1()
Dim Str As String
Dim Search As String
Dim X As Long
Dim Y As Long


X = 2
For Y = 2 To 6

Str = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(X, 5).Value
Search = Worksheets("FDSA").Cells(Y, 5).Value


    If Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(X, 4).Value = Worksheets("FDSA").Cells(Y, 3).Value And InStr(Search, Str) > 0 Then
        Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(X, 6).Value = "ok"
    Else

    End If
 Next Y


End Sub
```

After about a week of learning and failing Excel VBA I think I am very close to what I want it to do. I just need a bit of help with my last for loop.

The above code does exactly what I want it to do. I hardcoded the X with a value to debug it. I now need to loop the X to run through every cell in the row and do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub test1()
Dim Str As String
Dim Search As String
Dim X As Long
Dim Y As Long

For X = 2 To 92
Str = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(X, 5).Value

```
If Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(X, 6).Value = "" Then

    For Y = 2 To 96
    Search = Worksheets("FDSA").Cells(Y, 5).Value

            If Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(X, 4).Value = Worksheets("FDSA").Cells(Y, 3).Value And InStr(Search, Str) > 0 Then
                Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(X, 6).Value = "row" & Y
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(X, 6).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 200, 0)

            Else

            End If

    Next Y

Else

End If

    If Y = 97 And Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(X, 6).Value = "" Then
    Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(X, 6).Value = "N/A"
    Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(X, 6).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 0, 0)
    End If
```

Next X

End Sub

Figured it out, thanks either way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, loop inside the loop.

```
Sub test1()

Dim Str As String
Dim Search As String
Dim X As Long
Dim Y As Long


lastcolumn = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Column
'I don't how you data looks like... If there is always same amount of columns you can hard-code it... or calculate the last one like this..



For Y = 2 To 6

For X = 2 To lastcolumn 'start of second loop



Str = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(X, 5).Value
Search = Worksheets("FDSA").Cells(Y, 5).Value

If Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(X, 4).Value = Worksheets("FDSA").Cells(Y, 3).Value And InStr(Search, Str) > 0 Then
    Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(X, 6).Value = "ok"
Else

End If

Next X

Next Y

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Data Life, that was one of my next steps in my code. Figuring out how to incorporate an end to end  for both columns. i have now posted my own answer and will work on end to end. Thanks for the head start sir.